# what happen with the add(s,"Center");

Tags: java, swing

I'm a beginner and while preparing for my java exam I got stuck in the following code 
please tell me what is Center in "add(s,"Center");"

```
class TableTest extends JFrame {
    TableTest() {
        JTable table = new JTable(cells, columnNames);
        JScrollPane s = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(s, "Center"); 
    }

    private Object[][] cells = { { "111", "abc", "Trainee" }, { "222", "xyz", "Trainee" }, { "333", "ss", "CEO" }, };
    private String[] columnNames = { "Emp_ID", "Name", "Designation" };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TableTest tt = new TableTest();
        tt.setTitle("Table");
        tt.setSize(300, 200);
        tt.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        tt.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: `add(s, BorderLayout.CENTER)` would be better programming style See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html  and here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html#CENTER

Comment: Thanks, I got it  :-)

Comment: This code 1) extends frame for no good reason 2) sets an arbitrary size to the frame 3) uses 'magic numbers' 4) starts the GUI on a thread that is not the EDT 5) uses `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` when `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` would be more optimal 6) treats apparently numeric data (the `EMP_ID`) as strings. *"I'm a beginner and while preparing for my java exam I got stuck in the following code"* This code is not worth studying. In fact, it is crap code that teaches bad practices.

Comment: @AndrewThompson so from where should I learn Java and which book will be the best for beginners?

Comment: [The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I got stuck in the following code please tell me what is Center in "add(s,"Center");"

Code should not use "magic" values.

Instead the code should be using `BorderLayout.CENTER`. That value is a constraint used by the layout manager.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more information (and working exmaples) on what that constraint means.

Answer (score 0):

**"Center" expressing the layout constraints for this**